# Open PDF in IE without Addons

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf

I want to open pdf file in IE11, but i don't want to install Adobe Acrobat or reader or I don't want to add any add ons on IE.

Is it possible to open it?

Answer (score 0):

No. Unlike Edge, IE does not have a built-in PDF viewer.